# Gridview is not set at first page during binding

Tags: asp.net

I have dropdown list on my page. When I click on submit button, gridview is filled based on the choice in the dropdown list. It also contains pagging. Now when I move on page two and then change dropdown list value and again fill the grid, it fill perfectly but shows from the previous page index and not from the first page. I trid using "Gridveiw.PageIndex=0" but still its not working. What might be the reason behind this??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

first set `Gridveiw.PageIndex = 0;` like you are doing and then bind the grid.

Comment: you welcome, would you mind accepting this as an answer by clicking the tick mark on left :)